# Equation solving for approximate solutions when function has numerical integration in it

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerical-value

I have an equation that is of one variable `lat` and has a numerical integration in it `t` from 0 to 1.

Let's say it's given by `NIntegrate[f(lat,t),{t,0,1}]`. Now, I want to solve the equation for variable `lat` given `NIntegrate[f(lat,t),{t,0,1}] == c` where c is some constant value. `Solve[]` clearly doesn't work, is there a way to do this without implementing a loop guessing values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindRoot` might work, but you haven't given an example problem.  Making one up:

```
f[lat_, t_] := lat t^2
c = 5

FindRoot[NIntegrate[f[lat, t], {t, 0, 1}] - c, {lat, 1}]
(* {lat -> 15.} *)
```

Mathematica complains, but it gives the right answer.

```
NIntegrate[f[lat /. %, t], {t, 0, 1}]
(* 5. *)
```

A more complicated `f` may not work as well and you may have to play around with starting values.

Comment: thank you sir this works!

Comment: I'm glad it helps.